# JavaMail connect error (NO AUTHENTICATE) with OAuth 2.0

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have a background task in Java 8 which should read and process a MS365 mail file with OAuth 2.0.

A) The task is using "client credentials". The setup followed closely the instruction on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

B) The access token is created with

Endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555555555/oauth2/v2.0/token

Scope: https://outlook.office365.com/.default

The application ID and the secret seem to be correct as the authentication server returns a valid access token which can be base-64 decoded to a valid JSON JWT.

C) The following Javamail connect() to "outlook.office365.com:993" using the access token from step B) instead of the standard password returns "A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed"

```
Mail property mail.imaps.auth.login.disabe: true
Mail property mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable: true
Mail property mail.debug.auth.password: false
Mail property mail.mime.ignoreunknownencoding: true
Mail property mail.imaps.port: 993
Mail property mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms: XOAUTH2
Mail property mail.store.protocol: imaps
Mail property mail.imaps.ssl.enable: true
Mail property mail.imaps.partialfetch: false
Mail property mail.mime.decodetext.strict: false
Mail property mail.debug.auth: true
Mail property mail.imaps.peek: true
Mail property mail.imaps.sasl.enable: true

DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.partialfetch: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable SASL
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: peek
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [WgBSADAAUAAyADcAOABDAEEAMAAwADkAMAAuAEMASABFAFAAMgA3ADgALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=xxx@xxx.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL Mechanisms:
DEBUG IMAPS:  XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: 
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL client XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL callback length: 2
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL callback 0: javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@e2e750a
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL callback 1: javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback@8765a5d1
A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 
dXNlcj1h ... (Valid Token) ... AQ==
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

The authenticate string in the debug log (generated by JavaMail) decodes correctly back to the format "user=xxx@xxx.com auth=Bearer " followed by the access token.

What could cause the "NO AUTHENTICATE" error if the access token seems valid?

Thanks for any help
Andy Brunner

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

The PowerShell command was used with the object id of the App Registration screen.

But the object id must be taken from the Enterprise Application.